# ngInfiniteScroll not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble getting started with the ngInfiniteScroll directve. I've created a scope called movies which has about 150 objects of movies with titles and release dates. Using a ng-repeat I show the objects in a container element.

I've tried to create a sample app in plunker, but when I view the app it just shows all the records and the ngInfiniteScroll directive doesn't seem to do anything special.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bohgyL?p=preview

```
  <div infinite-scroll='myPagingFunction()' infinite-scroll-distance='3'> 
    <div class="repeat" ng-repeat="movie in movies | orderBy: '-release_date'">
      <h2> {{ movie.title }} </h2>
      <h2> {{ movie.release_date }} </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The desired result is that when you view the app you only see the results that are in your viewport, and when you scroll down additional results are inserted into the viewport. [Like this.](https://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html)

So what am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not showing us any code for `myPagingFunction()`, so I assume that to be the problem. That function doesn't exist out of the box, you need to make it. Refer to the example shown here: https://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html

If you do have a paging function, please show it to us so we can help debug your code.

Comment: That is indeed something I missed. I thought they added the function in the directive. I've tried to get started on the function, but I can't even get it to fire when the bottom of the page has been reached, as you can see here http://plnkr.co/edit/bohgyL?p=preview.

Comment: Check out this example here...http://plnkr.co/edit/nNxsEufjUPyW3T7gB6LS?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Zack, that helped out a lot. Don't understand it fully since it's a lot of JS (which I'm not good at). But I was wondering, you set a number `(var i=0;i<10;i++)` this does not scale well with browser size. Is there a way to fill a element to the bottom and add from there?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? The 10 was an arbitrary number; basically, every time you reach the bottom of the list (in this case, 10 items), it will add another 10 items to the list.

Comment: Depending on the styling and browser size it's possible that the viewport is large enough to show the set (in this case 10) number of elements. Which results in users not being able to scroll and thus not getting all the information. http://plnkr.co/edit/B7CRjvdQ9paytwl5csKi?p=preview If you view this plunker in a pop-up and resize it you should see what I'm getting it. If I view the pop up in full screen (1900x1200) then there not enough elements to cause a scrollbar, if I resize it to a smaller resolution (800x600) then I get a scrollbar and can view the extra content.

Comment: It's caused by your CSS. The element bound to `infinite-scroll` is not properly sizing to the height of the content, because every one of your "`repeat`" divs is floating. You need to add a clearfix.

Comment: I've tried to find additional information about how to use the clearfix in this content but I can't figure it out. Maybe I haven't explained my problem clearly, so I'll try it again. When I run the code I only see 10 results. If I change `(var i=0;i<10;i++)` to `(var i=0;i<30;i++)` I get 30 results. But what I want to see is that the element `#container-scroll` containing the `ng-repeat` element fills itself with results untill it's full to the bottom.